# Javascript: Print 1,000,000 "o"s on the page

Tags: javascript, loops

I keep trying to print 1,000,000 "o"s on the page but it keeps crashing. Is there a fast and easy way to **print 1,000,000 o's without using images**?

Comment: Show your codes.

Comment: Why do you need/want to print 1000000 o's on a page in the first place?

Comment: Doesn't every programmer need 1 million 'o's on a page??

Comment: Why so many downvotes? It was something I attempted out of curiosity.

Comment: @InvincibleBlaze typically, a question like this should include the code that you're having trouble with

Answer (score 2):

Using [`String.prototype.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

```js
const n = 100; // set this to 1000000 later
document.write('o'.repeat(n))
```

or [`Array.prototype.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

```js
const n = 100; // set this to 1000000 later
document.write(new Array(n).fill('o').join(''))
```

Comment: Ahhh beat me to it.

Comment: @xanth I was sitting here going *"there has to be a stringy way"*

Answer (score 1):

Faster

```js
const n = 1000000; // set this to 1000000
document.write("o".repeat(n))
```